# SaveAs the CSV file again as CSV and replace it with python code

Tags: tableau-api, pyautogui, read.csv

I have Problem to read CSV-Data completely in Tableau-Dashboard. The only way, which i found to solve this problem is, SaveAs the CSV file again as CSV and replace it with python code automaticly after the download the CSV.

I run the code with pyautogui in Virtual Mashine to SaveAs it again, but the Machine is forced to be log off after 10 min. Then the pyautogui does not work anymore.
I tried it with csv.read() and csv.write() but it does not help to solve the Data-Problem.
Could anybody please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please edit your question to contain all the information (code) - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)